# Random Infinite-loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, infinite-loop

I'm having an issue with this code I'm writing for a challenge.

The code I wrote goes in an infinite loop and I can't understand what's wrong.

```js
var wiggleMaxLength = function(nums) {
  let wiggleSteps = 1;
  let actualDiff, pastDiff, i;
  for (i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
    actualDiff = (nums[i] - nums[i - 1])
    if (nums[i] = 0) {
      nums.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
      continue;
    } else if ((pastDiff > 0 && actualDiff < 0)  || (pastDiff < 0 && actualDiff > 0) || (i = 1)) {
      pastDiff = actualDiff;
      wiggleSteps++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return wiggleSteps;
};
```

Comment: `if (nums[i] = 0) {` is no comparission, it's an assignment. Use `==` or `===`.

Comment: The first `if` statement is not checking if `nums[i]` equals `0`. It's changing `nums[i]` to `0` so the loop never ends because `nums[i]` never meets the equal value to stop it. Simply change `if (nums[i] = 0)` to `if (nums[i] == 0)`

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo on line 6 (`=` instead of `==` or `===`)

```js
if (nums[i] = 0)
```

I assume that you didn't see it.

This assigns the value `0` to `nums[i]`, instead of comparing nums[i] to 0.

Therefore, you should change the `if` into

```js
if (nums[i] == 0)
```

*or*

```js
if (nums[i] === 0)
```

**Note** that there is also an additional typo on line 9 in the 3rd condition `i = 1` instead of `i == 1` *or* `i === 1`, which is the reason that causes the infinite loop (as the counter 'i' is always re-assigned to 1).
The program always goes on the `else if` branch.

Comment: Could you also explain how this assignment leads to an infinite loop, please?

Comment: @Bergi I edited my answer above. I wouldn't have spotted the second typo if it weren't for running the code in my IDE in Debug Mode.